# Query>Checking with Today Date in VB

Tags: ms-access, date, vb6

I have created the database in Microsoft Access

with this query

```
 SELECT * from booking WHERE BOOK_DATE = DATE() order by book_time*
```

it returns 3 records which has BOOK_DATE = today date

but...

when i tried to place it in the Visual Basic with Data Control and DBGrid, i enter the query in the RecordSource property, but the data didnt come out when i execute the program

what did i miss about DATE()
doesn't it support in vb, shall i replace it with something else?

**WHERE BOOK_DATE = DATE()**

Comment: What does your VB code look like?

Comment: Its a plain form, with the query. if i give a query in the property like select * from booking, the DBGrid will show all the data in the table but it fails with WHERE BOOK_DATE = DATE()

Comment: with "select * from booking" i got this: http://i.imgur.com/wE1Y6.png
and with "SELECT * from booking WHERE BOOK_DATE = DATE() order by book_time" i got this: 
http://i.imgur.com/331Bi.png

Comment: Oh! i found something

the data in the table booking inside Access is different to the one calling from VB
http://i.imgur.com/KoF5m.png
why this possibly happen!

Comment: I believe that is just how Access displays the dates.  I'm still scratching my head as to why the query doesn't work.

Comment: I have another question..
From the begining i added the record to the table in access but later i changed some of the records BOOK_DATE field to the date 12 and 15 but... when it displays in VB, it seems to show the old data before i changed. im sure i already saved the file, how come it didnt change the value to the new one

Comment: What happens if you use 2010/10/12 instead of DATE() ? It seems that you may be running up against two different date displays. Access requires either US date format or an unambiguous date format.

Comment: im not sure whether i shall use single quote of double quote so i try both
select * from booking where BOOK_DATE = "2010/10/12"
select * from booking where BOOK_DATE = '2010/10/12'

vb informs with the msgbox ' Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Yep, I should have said that the date delimiter in Access is hash (#), so #2010/10/12#

Comment: Right, thats work perfectly.

The only problem left in my mind is that from the picture i.imgur.com/KoF5m.png  i have asked above
how could it be possible that the data shows on both side(access and vb) could be different. if i edited the record in access, why doesnt it update as i already saved it

Comment: I am not sure. Have you loaded the data again in VB to check that you are showing the latest data?

Comment: i just restarted my system but still the same
its like the access's db isn't the same database as the vb db called from access

Comment: Try putting SELECT Date() As DateTest, * and see what Date() is actually returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 knows about DATE() as I have used it recently.  I suspect that the data control can't handle a built in function such as DATE() in the RecordSource.   Can you change the RecordSource in the code, such as in the forms Open event or whatever approriate, to put in the date?  Something like:

```
Control.RecordSource="SELECT * from booking WHERE BOOK_DATE = " & _
     "#" &  DATE() & "# order by book_time*
```

Note that # are date delimiters similar to how ' or " (quotes or double quotes) are delimiters.   Assuming that the data control works the same as I'm used to in Access.  Also note though that you sometimes don't need those but you should be aware of them.

Also if any systems are running anything but mm/dd/yy format, or if there's even the slightest possibility this could happen then you should be ware of the following.

SQL statements require that the dates be either completely unambiguous or in mm/dd/yy, or mm/dd/yyyy format.   Otherwise Access/Jet will do it's best to interpret the date with unknown results depending on the specific date it is working with.  You can't assume that the system you are working on is using those date formats.   Thus you should use the logic at the following web page.
Return Dates in US #mm/dd/yyyy# format
http://www.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0005.htm

Comment: Perhaps you did not see all the comments? :)

Comment: ur syntax helps a lot, thx. at last i solved it :)
i got the solution from urs

my solved query> select table_id from booking where book_time = '" & lstBooking1_Time.Text & "' and book_date = #" & txtBooking1_Date.Text & "#"

Answer (score 0):

After I tried several ways i figure out that actually it was my fault.
But the new problem occurs

the query `SELECT * from booking WHERE BOOK_DATE = date()` is actually work in VB

the reason why it wasn't working because there is no records which contains BOOK_DATE = today date
But how could this happen because there are records which has BOOK_DATE = today date but VB just couldn't find it.

There is a possibility either the database i've made in MS Access or the VB itself has the error.
The same table shows in Access and VB is even different

let me explain. I have created the database in MS Access for a while with some records in it (i'm talking to only specific table 'booking')
so these records contain various date range.

but once i work with the VB, i thought that i want to try showing the data which has the 'today date' in the DBGrid, so i go back to my MS Access and edit some of the records, changing their date to either 12 Oct or 15 Oct 2010.

then i switch back to VB, i tried showing the data with the simple query `SELECT * from booking`. 
But the records that show in the table were the previous data before i've changed the date(12,15).

This is what i curious that why the data in Access that i've edited and saved but it didn't update in VB DBGrid.
It turns out whether how much more i change the information in the Access, the vb wont update the table but keep displaying the old one.

[image]

Comment: it turns out that i've saved the same database in 2 different directory with the same name. what a epic.

Comment: spending whole night to figure out this :( sad